# Read Config file of Another Application in WPF App by C#

Tags: c#, wpf, config, app-config

In my WPF Application( C#, .Net Framework 4.5 ),
I need to read another Applications config file.

```
         var configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap
            {
                ExeConfigFilename = "ChildApp.exe.config"
            };

          // Configuration object
          Configuration libConfig = 
           ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, 
            ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            // Get the section
            section = (libConfig.GetSection("appSettings") as 
                        AppSettingsSection);
            // Getting the value
            configValue = section.Settings["DBServer"];
```

But the configValue is getting nothing because there is no such value in the Setting dictionary.
     I also tried by using "userSettings" as in the config file, the section name is that.

```
section = (libConfig.GetSection("userSettings") as 
                        AppSettingsSection);
```

In this case, I am getting null in "section" value.

Here is my config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" 
    type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="ChildApp.Properties.Settings" 
 type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
  allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
 <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
 </startup>
 <userSettings>
    <ChildApp.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="DBServer" serializeAs="String">
            <value>MyServer</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="Database" serializeAs="String">
            <value>MyDatabase</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="DBUser" serializeAs="String">
            <value>sa</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="DBPassword" serializeAs="String">
            <value>password123</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="ErrorReportingEmail" serializeAs="String">
            <value>helpdesk@mydomain.com</value>
        </setting>
    </ChildApp.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
    </configuration>
```

I googled but could not find any solution which works.
Could you plz help me to figure out what is wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the usersettings like this:-

```
var user = (ConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("userSettings");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\bin\MyProject.dll.config");
            var p = xdoc.Element("configuration").Element("userSettings").Elements();
            foreach (XElement item in p)
            {
                if(item.FirstAttribute.Value == "DBServer")
                {
                    string dbserver = item.Value;
                }

            }
```

Load the config file in a XDoc and parse like above. you can get any field you want.

Here `using System.Xml.Linq;` need to be added.